# UILabel dynamic height iOS 7 with Views Below

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Similar things have been posted a hundred times here at SO, but I just cannot get my specific situation to work.

**My specific problem is:**
I have a `UILabel` that gets various amounts of text dynamically from a plist.
This label is inside a prototype cell in a table & I can get the cell to grow according to the amount of content.
I can get the 8 views that are below that cell in my prototype cell layout (two `UIImageView`s, a couple of other `UILabel`s, and a few `UIButton`s) to move down based on the size of the dynamic `UILabel`.

**Here's the problem:**
When I scroll down to see the full cell on the 3.5" iPhone in the simulator, the cell cuts off before the bottom of the cell, and on the 4" iPhone it is perfect.
When I fiddle with the height of the `UITableView` in the storyboard, it either cuts off more or not but it never hits the same way in both devices.
Oddly, when I make the `tableView` shorter in the storyboard, it makes the view longer (and the cell shows up) in both devices.

There's just no rhyme on the space below the last element in the prototype cell, and I can't seem to equalize it at all.

Any help would be appreciated.
I can't believe this is so difficult for me.

Comment: As the most desperate measure I suggest You create fresh project and add tableview and cell with necessary data using storyboard as in original project. - If the problem still persists - You can share Your  newly created demo project to us and we can try to help

Comment: how are you resizing the prototype cell and what Autolayout constraints or Autosizing settings have you used?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting staticVoidMan. I started a fresh table/prototype cell to give this a go and see if something stupid was happening, but I'm still getting the problem. Even with a single UILabel in the prototype cell. It's getting cut on the 3.5" phone in the simulator. Scrolling bounces to reveal almost the whole label, while the 4" phone is fine. AutoLayout constraints are default for trailing and leading to superview, and top and bottom are 20 pixels to superview.

Comment: Do I understand it right: your cells has different height and on devices with different screens sizes behave differently when the next one is dequeued? Because if so, perhaps the thing is that you dequeue different cells in both cases. With different height.

Comment: Ok so the plot thickens. Redid things again, and now it seems I'm having a weird relationship between the  scheme button and the size of the simulator. Exactly like this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885997/what-is-the-relationship-between-storyboard-form-factor-active-scheme-in-xcode

Comment: I'm losing my mind now. The Apply 3.5/4 inch Form Factor button on the storyboard actually has an effect on the project running in the simulators and on my actual device. Basically, selecting 3.5 in the storyboard and running it selecting 3.5-in simulator results in different spacing on the bottom of my cell. I'm guessing this is something to do with AutoLayout, but since my view is larger than a "regular" view in my storyboard (it has to be taller to accommodate everything), I can't figure this out. Never seen this happen. Any ideas?